# Getting data from a json file in IONIC using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

**Problem**

I created my first project with ionic framework using ionic tabs template  and this is an example of the project :
(https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs)
As we see in this project we get a list of  friends and a friend detail from an array list created in the services.js file, but I want to get this list and items detail  from a json file like this(example  https://friends.json).

**Question**

How can I Pull JSON data from a web server down to my app??

Comment: this an other example of the project in Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qYMCrt?p=preview

Answer (score 9):

**Factory in services.js**

Start off with a factory but replace my url wit yours.

```
.factory('Friends', function ($http, $rootScope, $stateParams) {

  return {
    all: function () {
      return $http.get('https://friends.json/all', { params: { user_id: $rootScope.session } })
    },
    get: function () {
      return $http.get('https://friends.json/getOne', { params: { user_id: $rootScope.session, chat_id: $stateParams.idchat } })
    },
    add: function (id) {
      return $http.get('https://friends.json/new', { params: {idfriends:id}})
    }
  };
});
```

**Controller in controllers.js**

Then make a controller like this. This is when you instantiate the factory to get your data.

```
.controller('FirendsCtrl', function ($scope, Friends) {

  Friends.all().success(function (response) {
    $scope.friends = response;
  })
})
```

**Scope added to View**

This will bind the data to the scope. And there for make it available to the view.

Finally you will be able to bring the data to the view via $scope
I have created a list here of all the friends that you get from get friend with a nice side swip to add more or delete.

```
<ion-view view-title="Contacts">
  <ion-content>
  <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-icon-right" ng-repeat="data in friends">
          <h1>{{ data.username }}</h1>
          <p>{{ data.friendNumber}}</p>
          <i class="icon ion-chevron-left icon-accessory"></i>
          <ion-option-button class="button-positive" ng-click="viewFriend(viewFriend(data.idfriends))">View Friend</ion-option-button>
          <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="deleteFriend(remove(data.idfriends))">Delete</ion-option-button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Disclaimer**

this is some code that I had previously written, I've modified it a bit to fit with your question. I have not ran this version exactly but my full version works fine.

if you wish to see the full code please feel free to check out my github repo https://github.com/joeLloyd/Scripto5000

Comment: Comment moved from [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39912214/5292302) by [Tomas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6936017/tomas), *there's a typo in your example of controllers.js; $scope.chats = response; should be $scope.friends = response;*, flag as obsolete this comment if you edited.

Comment: Heads up on 'firends' typo here too:

*.controller('FirendsCtrl', function